# Building Query from Multi-Selection Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am wondering how others would handle a scenario like such:

Say I have multiple choices for a user to choose from.

Like, Color, Size, Make, Model, etc.

What is the best solution or practice for handling the build of your query for this scneario?

so if they select 6 of the 8 possible colors, 4 of the possible 7 makes, and 8 of the 12 possible brands?

You could do dynamic OR statements or dynamic IN Statements, but I am trying to figure out if there is a better solution for handling this "WHERE" criteria type logic?

EDIT:
I am getting some really good feedback (thanks everyone)...one other thing to note is that some of the selections could even be like (40 of the selections out of the possible 46) so kind of large. Thanks again!

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best solution or practice for handling the build of your query for this scenario?

Dynamic SQL.

A single parameter represents two states - NULL/non-existent, or having a value.  Two more means squaring the number of parameters to get the number of total possibilities: 2 yields 4, 3 yields 9, etc.  A single, non-dynamic query can contain all the possibilities but will perform horribly between the use of:

1. ORs
2. overall non-[sargability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)
3. and inability to reuse the query plan

...when compared to a dynamic SQL query that constructs the query out of only the absolutely necessary parts.

The query plan is cached in SQL Server 2005+, if you use the `sp_executesql` command - it is not if you only use `EXEC`.

I highly recommend reading [The Curse and Blessing of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest doing is creating a function that takes in a delimited list of makeIds, colorIds, etc. This is probably going to be an int (or whatever your key is). And splits them into a table for you.

Your SP will take in a list of makes, colors, etc as you've said above.

`YourSP '1,4,7,11', '1,6,7', '6'`....

Inside your SP you'll call your splitting function, which will return a table-

```
SELECT * FROM
Cars C
JOIN YourFunction(@models) YF ON YF.Id = C.ModelId
JOIN YourFunction(@colors) YF2 ON YF2.Id = C.ColorId
```

Then, if they select nothing they get nothing. If they select everything, they'll get everything.

Comment: Note that this is only going to work if you've got your IDs client side in a name/value pair of sorts.

Comment: Thanks Mike this is similar to what I am doing in another scenario...does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

For something this complex, you may want a session table that you update when the user selects their criteria. Then you can join the session table to your items table.

This solution may not scale well to thousands of users, so be careful.

Comment: Bill can you provide some more information? That is an interesting idea. The other ideas below are good and similar to what I was thinking...my only issue with them is that some could have like 50+ inputs so I wanted to see if i fully understand what you are saying.

Comment: My idea is basically the same as bob's idea. His uses temp tables that are connection specific, so they clean themselves up at the end of the search. This works great as long as you don't have lots of concurrent users (and lots of concurrent temp tables).

I would use permanent tables and add some sort of session identifier so you could distinguish between User A's criteria and User B's criteria. You will have to clean it all up yourself, but scaling will be a little better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dynamic SQL it won't matter if you use the OR approach or the IN approach.  SQL Server will process the statements the same way (maybe with little variation in some situations.)

You may also consider using temp tables for this scenario.  You can insert the selections for each criteria into temp tables (e.g., #tmpColor, #tmpSize, #tmpMake, etc.).  Then you can create a non-dynamic SELECT statement.  Something like the following may work:

```
SELECT <column list>
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.ColorID in (SELECT ColorID FROM #tmpColor)
    OR MyTable.SizeID in (SELECT SizeID FROM #tmpSize)
    OR MyTable.MakeID in (SELECT MakeID FROM #tmpMake)
```

The dynamic OR/IN and the temp table solutions work fine if each condition is independent of the other conditions.  In other words, if you need to select rows where ((Color is Red and Size is Medium) or (Color is Green and Size is Large)) you'll need to try other solutions.